# Catch deadlock events in a background job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock

I'm currently catching deadlock events with the profiler. (deadlock, deadlock graph, deadlock chain).

So far so good, but for this, a client computer needs to be constantly running and online.

==> Is there a way to catch & collect deadlock events as a background job directly on SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deadlock events are captured by the system_health Extended Events trace so you don't need to run Profiler interactively or create a SQL Trace to capture the information.

Below is an example query to retrieve the deadlock info from the file target:

```
--Get xml_deadlock_report events from system_health session file target
WITH
      --get trace folder path and append session name with wildcard (assumes base file name is same as session name)
      all_trace_files AS (
        SELECT path + '\system_health*.xel' AS FileNamePattern
        FROM sys.dm_os_server_diagnostics_log_configurations
        )
      --get xml_deadlock_report events from all system_health trace files
    , deadlock_reports AS (
        SELECT CAST(event_data AS xml) AS deadlock_report_xml
        FROM all_trace_files
        CROSS APPLY sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file ( FileNamePattern, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS trace_records
        WHERE trace_records.object_name like 'xml_deadlock_report'
    )
SELECT TOP 10
      deadlock_report_xml.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS UtcTimestamp
    , deadlock_report_xml AS DeadlockReportXml
FROM deadlock_reports;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to use system_health is to use a dedicated XE session for deadlocks. It allow you to decide how much data you want to store, etc. Here's an example for such an XE session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Deadlocks] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'R:\Deadlocks',max_file_size=(1024),max_rollover_files=(3))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [Deadlocks] ON SERVER 
 WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON)

ALTER EVENT SESSION Deadlocks 
ON SERVER
STATE = START
```